# How to set the view of arrayadapter in listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to do the following:

1. Read data from `sqlite database`
2. Set those data in a `listview`

So I implemented a query to retrieve all the users in the database

SQLController.java

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
List<User> UserList = new ArrayList<User>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DBHelper.TABLE_USER;
 Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        User User = new User();
        User.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        User.setFname(cursor.getString(1));
        User.setLname(cursor.getString(2));
        User.setSex(cursor.getString(3));
        User.setAge(cursor.getString(4));
        // Adding User to list
        UserList.add(User);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return User list
return UserList;
```

}

Then I write the code below in the `MainActivity.java` that extends `Acticity`

```
    UserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.memberList_id);
    List<User> Users = dbcon.getAllUsers(); 
    ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.user, Users);
    UserList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I am 100% confused of what I should do next. I know I have to implement the `getView ()`but when I did it, too much errors appeared. 
So the question is, whats next? And what's wrong?

Comment: ListView lv=(ListView) findViewByID(R.id.user); ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Users); lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @ArmDroid  syntax error on `ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Users); ` The constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, List<User>) is undefined

Comment: ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user, Users);

Comment: @ArmDroid The method ArrayAdapter(MainActivity, int, List<User>) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments (Context, int, List<User>)

Comment: ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<User>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Users); try this way

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, best practice for the usage of cursor is to get cursor with column name:

```
String columnID = "ID";
String id;

id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnID));
```

Then, when you have to get the id of the listView by using findViewByID(id) method.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.list_id);
```

Setting the adapter after filling UserList is easy:

```
ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.user, Users);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what does `id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnID));` do ?

Comment: cursor.getColumnIndex(columnID) returns the index of that column named "ID".

Comment: great till now, where i will use the index of that column ?